# HttpWebRequest dynamic url

Tags: c#, .net

I am using 2 web servers for my development, 1 publish server and other one is for debugging. They dont have same urls.

I want to make a HttpWebRequest which works on both machines depending which server the code is on. My VS2010 project isnt a web application, so I dont have access to http context.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(rootofwebserver + "/webservices/someservice.asmx/someoperation");
```

This is what I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: You wrote exact code that you need... So what is the question? Maybe "how to provide configuration to my console application"?

Comment: 'rootofwebserver' is unknown. The question is how to get that? The Create method only accepts 'http://....' urls. So basically it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: what for you is *dynamic*? the server name comes from where exactly? database? list of known servers? any web service?

Comment: The question is, where I can get the server name? It is different from each web server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) element to setup your url:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="WebRequestUrl" value="..." />
</appSettings>
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
string webRequestUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebRequestUrl"];
```

Comment: I still think it will be static. The thing I need is: 

Server1 : http://server1.com/webservice/...
Server2 : http://server2.com/webservice/...

Comment: Thats what I dont want. I want something automated.

Comment: +1. @wiruzman, computers (an most people) can't go with just "something automated" - you need to explain exactly what you want. At this point your question is more like "I need code that will magically figure out Url I want it to use based on my mood and phase of the moon". No one can guess what url you want till you say what exactly you need. Maybe even `http://localhost` would work, who knows.

Comment: I dont want code to face my mood and stop blame me. Look at my question and yes it is a question about if it is possible the way I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can create .txt file and store your url and read again if you need. This is a simple way that i think.